# disable validation on bootstrap select field on button click using bootstrapValidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrapvalidator

I have a group of buttons and a bootstrap select field, when the first three buttons are clicked, the select field is disabled and when the fourth button is clicked it becomes enabled

The buttons and the select field are part of a form. how do I disable validation and hide the validation message on the select field when one of the first three buttons is clicked ?

Here is the HTML so you can get an idea about it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <style>
        #contact_form .btn-group .form-control-feedback {
            top: 0;
            right: -40px;
        }
        #success_message{ display: none;}
        .outputs {
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
        }
        .outputs_unit {
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap javascript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Validator -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Maps API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB03tJHy5QUZ_L3bjn3ehSkFE5QVrcSlLo&libraries=places"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS for bootstrap select-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript for bootstrap select-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        /* When the document gets ready */
        $(document).ready (
            function() {
                // Validation settings
                var validation_settings = {
                    excluded: [':disabled'],
                    feedbackIcons: {
                        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        "Truck Options": {
                            excluded: false,
                            validators: {
                                callback: {
                                    message: 'please select truck option',
                                    callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                                        var options = validator.getFieldElements("Truck Options").val();
                                        return (options != null && options.length === 1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Truck: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: '  Please choose a truck type',
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Enable validation for the form
                var form_validation = $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator(validation_settings);

                // revalidate everytime the select field is enabled
                $('#bootstrapSelectForm').find('[name="Truck Options"]').selectpicker().change(function(e) {
                    $('#bootstrapSelectForm').form_validation('revalidateField', 'Truck Options');
                }).end().form_validation;

                // Enable and disable the select field based on the button clicked
                $('.btn').on('click', function(){
                    var clicked_button = this.id;
                    if ( clicked_button === "53 foot reefer") {
                        truck_price_bool = false;
                        $('#truck_options_title').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#truck_options_title').selectpicker({'title': clicked_button});
                        $('#truck_options_title').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#truck_options_title').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('#truck_options_title').selectpicker('deselectAll');
                        $('#truck_options_title').selectpicker({'title': 'Choose from truck options'});
                        $('#truck_options_title').selectpicker('refresh');
                        truck_price_bool = true;
                    }
                });


            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <form class="pc_prevent_submit well form-horizontal" action="welcome.php" method="post"  id="contact_form" data-toggle="validator">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Truck type choice -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Truck type</label>
                <div class="btn-group col-md-8" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label id='Box truck' class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="Truck" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="Box truck" required> Box truck
                    </label>
                    <label id="Dry van" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="Truck" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="Dry van"> Dry van
                    </label>
                    <label id="Flat bed" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="Truck" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="Flat bed"> Flat bed
                    </label>
                    <label id="53 foot reefer" class="btn btn-primary"> 53 foot reefer
                        <input type="radio" name="Truck" id="option4" autocomplete="off" value="53 foot reefer">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Truck options -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Truck Options</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select name="Truck Options" id="truck_options_title" multiple title="Choose from truck options" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-max-options="1" disabled>
                        <option id="Frozen" title="Frozen">Frozen</option>
                        <option id="Chilled" title="Chilled">Chilled</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Book button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Success message -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-success col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" role="alert" id="success_message"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thank you for your request</div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div><!-- /.container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('#option1, #option2, #option3').on('click', function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators', 'Truck Options', false);
});
$('#option4').on('click', function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators', 'Truck Options', true);
});
```

http://formvalidation.io/api/#enable-field-validators

Comment: Did this work for you? If so please accept as the answer.